# Related products algorithm

Tags: php, mysql

When inserting products in an eshop we often need to link some products (aka related products) to others and the linking must be done both ways, meaning if I link product1 to product2 then product2 must also be linked to product1.

Which is the best practice, using an extra table 'relations' (prodid, related_prodid) or to keep a list of related products in a delimited string in each product's row in the products table?

In either case, we would also need a recursive method to loop through a given array of products and insert/update the tables with the relations, could someone help me out with the algorithm? I will do the PHP coding but I cant think of a good way to do it.

Comment: I think this question is too broad as you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use an intermediate table `related_to(id, product1, product2)`

Then, you'll use the code:

```
function findRelatedProducts($product) {
  $relatedProducts = array();
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM related_to WHERE product1='$product' OR product2='$product'");
  while ($relation = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $relatedProducts[] = $relation['product1'] == $product ? $relation['product2'] : $relation['product1'];
  }
  return $relatedProducts;
}
```

Of course, you need to `JOIN` this table with your product table, but since I don't have much informations about your mysql structure, I'll let you check on **[this site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)** if you don't know how.

Comment: Using two columns instead of one really helps, I used your example and did what I needed, thanks!

Comment: consider adding "weight" column. As some products might be more related to each other than others.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use the extra table (the string solution is really a bad idea), preferably organizing it so that the product with the lowest primary key is put first in the relation (allows for a bit of optimization); there is no need to duplicate the relationships (i.e. having  and  at the same time).
As for the recursive method thing, it's not clear where you get the relations' value from.